# Hosting site on Google Cloud Platform returns XML error

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform

I've created my bucket on Google Cloud with the appropriate site title, and installed Wordpress.

I then pointed Wordpress to my domain, but when I go to the domain I get the following error:

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated
>   with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<ListBucketResult xmlns="http://doc.s3.amazonaws.com/2006-03-01">
<Name>shop.site.com</Name>
<Prefix/>
<Marker/>
<IsTruncated>false</IsTruncated>
</ListBucketResult>
```

It was doing this before I installed Wordpress as well.

Some kind of security issue I think, but I've edited my bucket permissions and my default web page to be `index.php` but it's still showing this.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you're sure the problem was there before installing wordpress, how could it have anything to do with wordpress? Remove or shutdown wordpress to eliminate it interfering with troubleshooting, and figure out the root cause from there. Clearly something else is going on. Post URL used etc.

Comment: Did you follow the proper documentation on how to configure a Cloud Storage Bucket to host a static website [https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website]?

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error when hosting a new static website until if used the instructions here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/web

That may or may not be the problem in this case, though.

Comment: This is rather than a comment instead of answering the question

Answer (score 0):

You must use the gsutil command line to set the `main_page_suffix`.

```
gsutil web set -m index.html -e 404.html gs://example.com
```